# How to detect the Display cutout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {

        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    DisplayCutout displayCutout = insets.getDisplayCutout();
                    if (displayCutout != null) {
                        // Display cutout is present
                        Log.d(TAG, "Display cutout detected");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // No display cutout
                        Log.d(TAG, "No display cutout detected");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
            }
```

I'm using the above code to detect if a cutout is present or not. But for the devices with cutout/ notch present it is still showing that there is no display cutout present.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get display cutouts (with approriate null checks):

```
// Get the actual screen size in pixels
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
MainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
// if there are no cutouts, top and left offsets are zero
int top = 0;
int left = 0;
// get any cutouts
DisplayCutout displayCutout = MainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getCutout();
// check if there are any cutouts
if (displayCutout != null && displayCutout.getBoundingRects().size() > 0) {
    // add safe insets together to shrink width and height
    width -= (displayCutout.getSafeInsetLeft() + displayCutout.getSafeInsetRight());
    height -= (displayCutout.getSafeInsetTop() + displayCutout.getSafeInsetBottom());
    // NOTE:: with LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES, we can render on the whole screen
    // NOTE::    and therefore we CAN and MUST set the top/left offset to avoid the cutouts.
    top = displayCutout.getSafeInsetTop();
    left = displayCutout.getSafeInsetLeft();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set layoutInDisplayCutoutMode first. Add this line before get getDisplayCutout

```
getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
```